# Asp.net objectdatasource TypeName property error

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I use `ASP:ObjectDataSource` for grid data binding.

My problem is when I run this code I get error.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsListing" 
runat = "server"  
SelectMethod = "MethodNameOfCodeBehindClass"
TypeName = "FolderName_CodeBehindClassName" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Error message

```
The type specified in the TypeName property of 
ObjectDataSource 'odsListing' could not be found.
```

So I move my code to codebehind site.

```
    #region ObjectDataSource for Grid Binding
    Type type = typeof(FolderName_CodeBehindClassName);
    string assemblyQualifiedName = type.AssemblyQualifiedName;

    odsListing.TypeName = assemblyQualifiedName;
    odsListing.SelectMethod = "ListingDatabind";
    #endregion
```

Now Everythings is ok. It is work.
But I would like to know actual solution for my problem.
Why it raise error?

Actually, I don't want to move my code to codebehind layer if it can write at design layer.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using short type name instead of full type name.

Replace `FolderName_CodeBehindClassName` with `The.NameSpace.YouHaveYourTypeIn.FolderName_CodeBehindClassName, Name.Of.Your.Assembly`.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Web Site which has no assembly and even no namespace have. So how could I do it please ?

Comment: Omit the assembly. However, I am almost sure that your class is in some namespace. The problem with VB is that even if you don't have namespace in code, there's the default namespace. Take a look at project properties and find a textbox "default namespace".