# Typename cannot be found in objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net page with a gridview and objectdatasource. The Select Method that the objectdatasource should call is in the code behind on the same page. When I try to reference a method in the code behind I keep getting the following error:

**"The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'odsReplacementRequests' could not be found."**

I have tried using different combinations of the typename. examples

Typename = ""
Typename = Testing

**Page is called Testing.aspx**

```
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsReplacementRequests" runat="server" EnablePaging="true"
    SelectMethod="GetReplacementRequests"  TypeName="ASP.retail_gpreplacements_aspx">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

    /// <summary>
/// Get replacements 
/// </summary>
public List<ReplacementRequests> GetReplacementRequests()
{

    List<ReplacementRequests> r = new List<ReplacementRequests>();
    ReplacementRequests rp1 = new ReplacementRequests() { CustomerNumber = "12300", PhoneNumber = "778-123-2132" };
    ReplacementRequests rp2 = new ReplacementRequests() { CustomerNumber = "12301", PhoneNumber = "778-123-2132" };

    r.Add(rp1);
    r.Add(rp2);

    return r;
}
```

** Update

I've used the following code to get the typename of the code-behind class

```
    /// <summary>
/// Page Load
/// </summary>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    odsReplacementRequests.TypeName = this.GetType().ToString();
}
```

Still no luck...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are omitting the `TypeName` property on the `ObjectDataSource`, it defaults to an empty string. You need to have the type name be the fully qualified name of the class where your `SelectMethod` is defined (i.e. the namespace in your `Testing.aspx` file plus the class name), like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsReplacementRequests" runat="server" 
                      EnablePaging="true"
                      TypeName="YourNamespace.SubNamespace.Testing"
                      SelectMethod="GetReplacementRequests">
```

> Note: You may or may not have a sub namespace, but just copy the `namespace` from your code-behind and add a dot and the class name to that end of that string.

---

Also, `GetGPReplacementRequests` != `GetReplacementRequests`.

Your `SelectMethod` attribute in the `ObjectDataSource` is pointing at `GetGPReplacementRequests`, but your code-behind has a method named `GetReplacementRequests`, change the `SelectMethod` to that name, like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsReplacementRequests" runat="server" 
                      EnablePaging="true"
                      SelectMethod="GetReplacementRequests">
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. I've updated it now and it still comes up with that error

Comment: Hi Karl, I'm using a website project and when I stuck the code to determine the type in the page load I got the following. ASP.retail_gpreplacements_aspx and I used that as the typename but no luck

Comment: @chobo - if you right click on your website and then click Properties, is there a default namespace defined?

Comment: No I couldn't find a reference to a namespace. It's a website project so it has that app_code directory and such

Comment: What is the name of your class? `Testing`?

Comment: I have the same situation as @chobo. I have a website project and I used code in the page load to see what type I get and it is like what chobo got and I used it but it complains. I tried every combination I could think of. I am not sure what _right click on your website and then click Properties_ is but I can't find a namespace configured anywhere.

Comment: See [c# - The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource could not be found - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328819/the-type-specified-in-the-typename-property-of-objectdatasource-could-not-be-fou). Using Page_Init seems to have solved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the typename from where your SelectMethod exists and fix name of SelectMethod

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsReplacementRequests" runat="server" EnablePaging="true"
                      TypeName="NameSpace.Testing"
                      SelectMethod="GetReplacementRequests">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

For additional info check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on SelectMethod